# How to add multiple collections of firestore in a listview builder in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-listview

Below is the code which is successfully running and adding the list of documents from the collection in firestore for a single query.

```
return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index){
      String itemTitle = snapshot.data.documents[index]['postContent'];

      List steps = List.castFrom(snapshot.data.documents[index]["steps"]);
      String pic1 = snapshot.data.documents[index]['pic1'];
   return NameCard(name: Name,steps: steps,p1: pic1,
      );

    });
```

I want to add multiple queries to the same listview.builder?
below are the queries, how should I do that?

QUERIES

```
Query query  = Firestore.instance.collection('names');
Query query2  = Firestore.instance.collection('names2');
Query query3  = Firestore.instance.collection('names3');
```

Comment: go one after one,....or make 3 FutureBuilder , but it will be more complex while handling errors/null data and also requires more time....

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you change your database to the following:

```
Names(Collection) --> (names)  Document
                      (names2) Document
                      (names3) Document
```

Then you can do:

```
Query query  = Firestore.instance.collection('Names');
```

and it will get all the `names` documents.

Comment: peter, i understand your point, then how to get all the subcollections in the same list? the things is "names, names2 and names3" are all different collections with different set of documents and i want all to be in the same list, hows that possible?

Comment: I mean change the database to be able to make this query, instead of names,names2,names3 having them as collection, make them as documents

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new list by combining the three queries

```
var newList = [...list1, ...list2, ...list3]
```

Provide the code where you are requesting the snapshot for the exact workaround.